# Trying to link to an external stylesheet using media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been trying to set my website to where, when it hits 400px or less it uses an external style sheet.

I don't know why but nothing seems to be changing, it's supposed to change the layout for tablets, phones, etc. But nothing has changed, if anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

This is my code:

```html
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen (max-width: 400px;)" href="style2.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have bad `media` attribute value, missing `and`

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 400px;)" href="style2.css">
```